# Extract string from NSString

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsstring

```
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithString:@"The dog ate the cat"];
```

How to extract word from above string that starts with "at".

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html

Comment: how about be more precise: linked page has 10 million lines

Comment: @M Holod there are the "option" and "F" keys on the keyboard...

Comment: After searching through and across I was able to get anything before or after the "at" but not the actual "cat" from the string. Just does not work for me, thus the question here. Was using componentsSeparatedByString, ranges, substring, etc. to no avail. Intention was to manage the thing without using an array. But if i don't get other answers I will accept Eimantas answer.

Comment: You stated you need words STARTING WITH, not containing "at".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [NSRegularExpression](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class.

```
NSString *str = @"The dog ate the cat";
NSError *error = NULL;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression
                              regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(at\\w+)"
                              options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                              error:&error];
[regex enumerateMatchesInString:str options:0
                          range:NSMakeRange(0, str.length)
                     usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *match, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop)
{
    NSString *result = [str substringWithRange:match.range];
    NSLog(@"%@", result);
}];
```

Answer (score 3):

```
NSArray *words = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF BEGINSWITH %@", @"at"];
NSArray *wordsStartingWithAt = [words filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```